# How to get the docker containers information with Ruby and monitor it

Tags: ruby, docker

I want to get the containers' stats. eg: `CPU, Memory`

I only know the command `docker stats <CONTAINER NAME>`, but when I type the command, it will be blocking in the foreground(like you typed `top` command)

But I want get those information with `Ruby`.

Then decide the action by those information, such as restart container or something else.

Thanks ~

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should access it from [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) but not [Docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/)

So if you want get container stats, you can do it through `GET /containers/(id)/stats` API and parse the response with ruby.

Also, I found a ruby [repo](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api) might helpful.